# How to update datagridview before changing model?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I read file and fill data from this file in `List<ClientJson> data`. After I try to update datagrid, I tried several ways, but do not work one of them.

```
public void dataGridClientsLoad()
        {

            ReaderDb reader = new ReaderDb();

            List<ClientJson> data = reader.localTemp();

            if (data != null)
            {


                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = typeof(List<>);
                this.dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
                this.dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
                this.dataGridView1.Refresh();



            }

        }
```

I call function above from another form like as:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();

form.dataGridClientsLoad();
```